# Conditional Components rendering error in React page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

-Users.js

```
const Users = () => {
  const { page_type } = useParams();

  console.log(page_type);

  return (
    <div className="Users">
      <h2>로그인/회원가입</h2>

      {page_type === "login" && <Login />}
      {page_type === "join" && <Join />}
      {page_type === "resetPw" && <ResetPw />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Users;
```

-App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/users/:page_type" element={<Users />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="/detail/:goods_id" element={<Goods />} />
          <Route path="/mypage/:user_id" element={<MyPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

- Login.js

```
<button onClick={navigate("/users/join")}>Join</button>
<button onClick={navigate("/users/resetPw")}>resetPw</button>
```

I am implementing the login and membership page with React
By page routing, '/users/:page_type' url becomes Users Components, and I want this component to be exchanged according to url's parameter, which receives the child components Login and Join Components as conditional rendering.
But as a result of the implementation, clicking the join button leads to '/users/resetPw', and going backwards leads to join again How can I solve this? Help me please...

Comment: You've a typo in your buttons' `onClick` handlers causing the navigation actions to be immediately effected. `onClick={navigate("/users/join")}` should be `onClick={() => navigate("/users/join")}` so they are only effected when the buttons are clicked. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the way you setup your `onClick` handlers on the buttons. Currently you're directly calling/executing them, instead what you should do is pass a anonymous function like so:

```js
<button onClick={() => navigate("/users/join")}>Join</button>
<button onClick={() => navigate("/users/resetPw")}>resetPw</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

To fix the issue, use the useEffect hook in the Users component to update the page_type whenever the URL changes. This ensures the component re-renders with the correct page_type value, fixing the conditional rendering problem.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './Login';
import Join from './Join';
import ResetPw from './ResetPw';

const Users = () => {
  const { page_type } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    // This effect will run whenever the URL parameter (page_type) changes
    // It ensures that the page_type in the component stays in sync with the URL
    // and will re-render the component with the correct page_type value.
  }, [page_type]);

  const handleJoinClick = () => {
    navigate('/users/join');
  };

  const handleResetPwClick = () => {
    navigate('/users/resetPw');
  };

  return (
    <div className="Users">
      <h2>로그인/회원가입</h2>

      {page_type === 'login' && <Login />}
      {page_type === 'join' && <Join />}
      {page_type === 'resetPw' && <ResetPw />}

      {/* Add click handlers to the buttons */}
      <button onClick={handleJoinClick}>Join</button>
      <button onClick={handleResetPwClick}>resetPw</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Users;
```